# MongoDB - filter in find function

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a query in mongo db. I want to know that how do I use substring function in find function, like I have a date string. I want to filter the date by year and then group by month.
This is what I have tried:

```
db.booking.find({$substr:["$bookingdatetime",5,2]:"14"}).aggregate([     {$group: {         _id: {$substr: ['$bookingdatetime', 5, 2]},          numberofbookings: {$sum: 1}     }} ])
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: `$substr` is an aggregation operator. You can't use it in a `find()` statement.

Comment: So, what do I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

[$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) can be used only as a string aggregation operation. You cannot use it as a operator in a find query. You can form the aggregation pipeline as below:

```
db.booking.aggregate([
{$project:{"year":{$substr:["$bookingdatetime",5,2]},
           "numberofbookings":1,
           "bookingdatetime":1}},
{$match:{"year":14}},
{$group:{"_id":{$substr: ['$bookingdatetime', 5, 2]},
         numberofbookings: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

or,

use a [regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to match the date pattern with specific year.

Comment: The year depends on the date given, I can't hard code it.